# disable a button in a FormView

Tags: c#, formview

I have a button in a formview and would like to make a button invisible if a condition is false. for the first record the below code works fine.

```
FormView1.FindControl("btnnext").Visible = false;
```

but on the second record the button stays visible. I have put the same code within a posback code.

how can I make it invisible please?

Comment: The button is inside a repeater or list or something? You say "second record".

Comment: Why dont you Visible="false" on the button it self? Yo ucan do this by changing it to a template-field

Comment: no its inside a formview databound to a list of records from a sql database.

Comment: how can I change the template field pls?

Comment: Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx